# DRF + Angular - do object records need to be declared in both?

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

If I use DRF to create an API backend, and Angular for the front end, will I need to create the data structures in both?

For example if the DRF had a `User` model with `first_name`, `last_name`, etc then wouldn't Angular also need to create an object with a similar structure in order to present it/manipulate it? It seems like a DRF + Angular setup is a solid way to go, but I feel like the defining of models in the DRF and Angular is redundant (though necessary) step.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT** For Clarity on what I'm trying to get at:

I'm working through the Angular **2** tutorial, and they have a `Hero` class, which has two properties (`id`, and `name`). If I were to then populate an array of Hero's from my backend (DRF), then I'd need to have a `Hero` class/model/object defined on my backend with the same properties holding the actual values. This is what I was trying to get at -- it seems like the `Hero` object needs to be defined in both the backend and the frontend.

Comment: Angular, being a JavaScript framework, uses Object prototypes, where properties can be added or removed at any time.  Defining a model isn't really a correct description of how angular works;  Models are defined by the properties that **are** added, not defined as the properties that **will be** added.

Comment: @Claies I'm new to Angular, so still getting used to the terminology. I'm working through the tutorial, and they have a `Hero` class, which has two properties (`id`, and `name`). If I were to then populate an array of `Hero`'s from my backend, then I'd need to have a `Hero` class/model/object defined on my backend with the same properties holding the actual values. This is what I was trying to get at -- it seemse like the `Hero` object needs to be defined in both the backend and the frontend. Would that be correct or am I still misunderstanding something?

Comment: you must be referring to [Angular 2](http://angular.io), not [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org).  They are similar, but Angular2 is built on ES6 / Typescript, where class definitions are different.  There is a completely different group of tags for the rewritten version.

Comment: @Claies Yes, Angular2. I think the basic question still stands, no? It seems like I need to define the `Hero` object in the frontend and the backend.

Comment: in Angular2, especially using TypeScript, yes.  In angularjs, however, models are not handled the same.